# Highlighting Text Editor

Tags: text-editor, syntax-highlighting

I need a text editor (for programming pourposes) that supports the following features:

1. Multi-Language syntax-highlighting
2. Mult-plataform (UNIX/Windows)
3. Graphical Interface
4. Square Block of Text selection

On windows, I use ConTEXT, but, it is not Mult-plataform (issue 2). 
On Linux I use Gedit, but, fails on issue 4.

---

Is there any editor that suits all these needs?

EDIT:

Issue 4 is, select a square (or rectangle if you wish) like this:

```
aaaaaaaa|aaaa|aaxxxxxa 
bbbbbbbb|bbbb|bbbxxxxx
cccccccc|cccc|cccxxxxx
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean with point 4... can you explain? (If you mean selecting a "rectangle" of text, then you can do it in Gedit with this plugin http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins/ColumnMode )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multi platform? Emacs or gVim.

Comment: I can strongly recommend (g)Vim. If you’ve heard spooky things about Vim and its newbie-unfriendly modal behavior, have a look at its “easy mode”.

Answer (score -1):

The etherpad plugin ep_codepad provides syntax highlighting - based on highlight.js - for etherpad.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ep_codepad [drive mad](https://drivingmad.io)